# Can not set font color in conditional formatting cell via apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

My purpose is to copy conditional formatting rules from one sheet to another, where two sheets are not in same workbook via apache poi. For this purpose I am using the following code;

```
for(int i=0;i<sscf.getNumConditionalFormattings();i++){

        ConditionalFormatting cf = sscf.getConditionalFormattingAt(i);
        CellRangeAddress[] range = cf.getFormattingRanges();

        //getting various properties from source
        ConditionalFormattingRule rule = cf.getRule(0);

        PatternFormatting pattern = rule.getPatternFormatting();
        Color bgcolor = pattern.getFillBackgroundColorColor();
        Color fgcolor = pattern.getFillForegroundColorColor();
        Short fillPattern = pattern.getFillPattern();

        FontFormatting font = rule.getFontFormatting();
        int colorIndex = font.getFontColorIndex();
        Color fontColor = font.getFontColor();
        int fontHeight = font.getFontHeight();
        short ulType = font.getUnderlineType();

        //--------------------------------End of getting------------------------------

        //setting properties from source
        ConditionalFormattingRule newRule = dscf.createConditionalFormattingRule(rule.getFormula1());
        PatternFormatting newPattern = newRule.createPatternFormatting();
        FontFormatting newFont = newRule.createFontFormatting();

        if(bgcolor != null)
            newPattern.setFillBackgroundColor(bgcolor);

        if(fgcolor != null)
            newPattern.setFillForegroundColor(fgcolor);

        if(fillPattern != 0)
            newPattern.setFillPattern(fillPattern);

        if(colorIndex != 0)
            newFont.setFontColorIndex((short) colorIndex);

        if(fontColor != null)             
            newFont.setFontColor(fontColor);   //<-----This line

        if(fontHeight != 0)
            newFont.setFontHeight(fontHeight);

        if(ulType != 0)
            newFont.setUnderlineType(ulType);

        dscf.addConditionalFormatting(range,newRule);
    }
```

Everything is working fine except **I can not set font color of conditional formatting cells in destination sheet**.

Two things I noticed;

1st : colorIndex of source sheet always becomes 0 (Though my font color in source sheet is green or red)

2nd : I am getting an exception in line pointed with *This line* as follow

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl.CTFontImpl.setColorArray(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFontFormatting.setFontColor(XSSFFontFormatting.java:123)
at processor.ExcelTemplateProcessor.copyConditionalFormattingRules(ExcelTemplateProcessor.java:799)
at processor.ExcelTemplateProcessor.copySheet(ExcelTemplateProcessor.java:163)
at processor.ExcelTemplateProcessor.copySheet(ExcelTemplateProcessor.java:128)
at processor.ExcelTemplateProcessor.createReport(ExcelTemplateProcessor.java:117)
at service.TemplateReportService.createReport(TemplateReportService.java:189)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:62)
```

I tried to search almost everywhere about the cause, but could not find out a solution.

Can you please mention if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: There is a bug in [XSSFFontFormatting.setFontColor](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_16_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFontFormatting.java?revision=1791046&view=markup#l118). The `_font.setColorArray(0, xcolor.getCTColor());` will always fail if there is not a `ColorArray` already. Needs to be checked and used [CTFont.addNewColor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTFont.java#CTFont.addNewColor%28%29) if not already present.

Comment: Raise a bug in the Apache POI bugzilla for this? Looks like you have most of a unit test to reproduce it, which is almost all that's needed!

Comment: Ok, I understand the issue. But is there anything for now to bypass it? I have an urgent requirement actually. @AxelRichter

Comment: @Gagravarr: The bug is obvious. No unit test necessary to reproduce it. **Never** try accessing an array item without knowing (checking) that it will exist!

Comment: @KOUSIK MANDAL: Sorry no fast bypass except to patch the XSSFFontFormatting.java yourself.

Comment: @AxelRichter But without a bug in the POI bugzilla, it risks getting forgotten about and not fixed!