# Conditional formatting working in Excel 2007 but not in Excel 2016

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am in a situation where I have put conditional formatting by formula like;

```
=COUNTIF($A14,"*~*")>0
```

For Cell E14 to E38.

Now this is working pretty fine in Excel 2007 but not working at all in Excel 2016.
I inspected the XML file which is like;

```
<conditionalFormatting sqref="E14:E38">
    <cfRule priority="1" dxfId="0" type="expression">
        <formula>COUNTIF($A14,"*~*")>0</formula>
    </cfRule>
</conditionalFormatting>
```

Even if I delete the rules and adding it again it is not working. I tried other rule but for those cells conditional formatting is not working at all.

FYI, I have set up print area and conditional formatting inside print area is not working for any cell but it is working pretty well outside print area.

All these problems are in Excel 2016 only.

**N.B. I am creating the excel file using Apache POI**

Basically I am copying conditional formatting from once excel sheet to another. Code as below;

```
    private void copyConditionalFormattingRules(Sheet source,Sheet destination){

        try{
            SheetConditionalFormatting sscf= source.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
            SheetConditionalFormatting dscf= destination.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
            //SheetConditionalFormatting dscf0= ((XSSFSheet)destination).getSheetConditionalFormatting();

            // delete existng formattings,if any
            for(int i=0;i<dscf.getNumConditionalFormattings();i++){

                dscf.removeConditionalFormatting(i);                    
            }

            //looping over all conditional formattings
            for(int i=0;i<sscf.getNumConditionalFormattings();i++){

                ConditionalFormatting cf = sscf.getConditionalFormattingAt(i);
                ConditionalFormatting cf1 = sscf.getConditionalFormattingAt(i);


                CellRangeAddress[] range = cf.getFormattingRanges();

                for(int j=0;j<cf.getNumberOfRules();j++){

                    //getting various properties from source
                    ConditionalFormattingRule rule = cf.getRule(j);
                    String formula1 = rule.getFormula1();

                    //creating new rule for destination sheet
                    ConditionalFormattingRule newRule = dscf.createConditionalFormattingRule(formula1);

                    try{
                        //Get pattern formatting
                        PatternFormatting pattern = rule.getPatternFormatting();
                        PatternFormatting newPattern = newRule.createPatternFormatting();

                        //retrieve pattern information
                        Color bgcolor = pattern.getFillBackgroundColorColor();
                        Color fgcolor = pattern.getFillForegroundColorColor();
                        short bgcolor1 = pattern.getFillBackgroundColor();
                        short fgcolor1 = pattern.getFillForegroundColor();
                        short fillPattern = pattern.getFillPattern();

                        if(bgcolor != null)
                            newPattern.setFillBackgroundColor(bgcolor);

                        if(bgcolor1 != 0)
                            newPattern.setFillBackgroundColor(bgcolor1);

                        if(fgcolor != null)
                            newPattern.setFillForegroundColor(fgcolor);

                        if(fgcolor1 != 0)
                            newPattern.setFillBackgroundColor(fgcolor1);

                        if(fillPattern != 0)
                            newPattern.setFillPattern(fillPattern);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    try{
                        //Get font formatting
                        FontFormatting font = rule.getFontFormatting();

                        FontFormatting newFont = newRule.createFontFormatting();

                        if(font != null) {
                            //retrieve font information
                            int colorIndex = font.getFontColorIndex();
                            Color fontColor = font.getFontColor();
                            int fontHeight = font.getFontHeight();
                            short ulType = font.getUnderlineType();


                            if(colorIndex != 0)
                                newFont.setFontColorIndex((short) colorIndex);

                            if(fontColor != null){
                                //currently font color not working
                                //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611870/can-not-set-font-color-in-conditional-formatting-cell-via-apache-poi
                                try{
                                    newFont.setFontColor(fontColor);
                                }catch(Exception e){

                                }
                            }

                            if(fontHeight != 0)
                                newFont.setFontHeight(fontHeight);

                            if(ulType != 0)
                                newFont.setUnderlineType(ulType);
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    try{
                        //Get border formatting
                        BorderFormatting borderFormatting = rule.getBorderFormatting();
                        BorderFormatting newBorderFormatting = newRule.createBorderFormatting();

                        if(borderFormatting != null) {
                            //retrieve border information
                            int bBottom = borderFormatting.getBorderBottom();
                            int bLeft = borderFormatting.getBorderLeft();
                            int bDiagonal = borderFormatting.getBorderDiagonal();
                            int bTop = borderFormatting.getBorderTop();
                            int bRight = borderFormatting.getBorderRight();
                            int bBottomColor = borderFormatting.getBottomBorderColor();
                            int bTopColor = borderFormatting.getTopBorderColor();
                            int bRightColor = borderFormatting.getRightBorderColor();
                            int bLeftColor = borderFormatting.getLeftBorderColor();
                            int bDiagonalColor = borderFormatting.getDiagonalBorderColor();


                            if(bBottom != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setBorderBottom((short) bBottom);

                            if(bTop != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setBorderBottom((short) bTop);

                            if(bLeft != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setBorderBottom((short) bLeft);

                            if(bRight != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setBorderBottom((short) bRight);

                            if(bDiagonal != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setBorderBottom((short) bDiagonal);

                            if(bBottomColor != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setBottomBorderColor((short) bBottomColor);

                            if(bTopColor != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setTopBorderColor((short) bTopColor);

                            if(bLeftColor != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setLeftBorderColor((short) bLeftColor);

                            if(bRightColor != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setRightBorderColor((short) bRightColor);

                            if(bDiagonalColor != 0)
                                newBorderFormatting.setDiagonalBorderColor((short) bDiagonalColor);
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //--------------------------------End of getting------------------------------

                    //setting properties from source


                    dscf.addConditionalFormatting(range,newRule);
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help will be extremely good for me. If you need any more details please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible issue is that Excel treats the tilde symbol `~` as a literal indicator [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/603266/working-with-in-excel).

Comment: If you create what you want in Excel, then look at the XML, how does that differ? And if you feed that same form back to Apache POI, does that then work?